# Как запустить скрипт из другого скрипта с определённым версией Python?

Tags: python, qt

Я хочу сделать лаунчер, который запускает программу разных версий. А лаунчер сделан на Python Qt Designer а точнее на версии Python 3.4.0. И вот когда я сделать кнопку которая запускает программу. Выходит ошибка - того что лаунчер сделан на 3.4.0 а программа которую надо запустить на 3.10.0.

Что мне делать?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не совсем понял в виду чего ошибка, но учитывая, что ответов нет, предложу свое решение:

Вы можете запустить Python-скрипт (или любую другую программу) с указанной версией в консоли вашей ОС из своего скрипта, выглядит это так (на примере Linux):

```
os.system("python3.10 start_script.py")
```

Это команда запустит указанный скрипт

Подробнее о подобных методах запуска на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command)

Comment: Этот ответ бы мне помог. Но я хочу превратить программу в EXE для других ПК. А у других ПК не может быть Python.

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, вы хотите запустить Python-скрипт без установленного Python'a?
Для подобных целей я использовал [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/index.html) , он объединит все зависимости в один пакет, который можно запускать на машине без установленного Python

Comment: Вы не так меня поняли, первая программа будет в EXE. А второй будет в PYTHON формате. Первый скрипт должен запустить другой. Как это сделать? Я знаю про `exec(open("main.py").read())`, но он не запускает скрипт, а просто к своему прибавляет эти строки кода.